# Can anyone help me fill in the blanks of a kid's rhyme?

Tags: phrases, set-phrases, song-lyrics, song

My 4 year old has been going to a Japanese preschool for a few weeks and has picked up a rhyme/chant that all the kids say before they eat. I'd love to learn it too so we can say it together at home, but I'm struggling to find anything when I try to Google it. Hopefully it's famous enough that someone knows it well!

I think I have most of it, but she could be saying it wrong (plus I'm still very much learning Japanese), so any corrections are welcome!
Thanks in advance for any help.

準備はいいですか？

いいですよ！

。。。<--- this is the line I cant make out

皆でどうぞいただきます

どうぞ召し上がれ

ありがとう！

どういたしまして

はい！

Comment: I have a feeling this is something you should ask the teacher or other parents.

Comment: 園によって異なりますよね。　https://mamastar.jp/bbs/comment.do?topicId=1369297